# Steps for upgrading iOS phonegap app to iOS native app

Tags: ios, cordova, uistoryboard

I have an apps which is currently in app store but it's phonegap base and the UI is sluggish. I want to build native for this app.

The problem is if I create a new project, the bundle identifier must be different from the previous one and this will be consider a new app in app store and existing user will not be able to update their copy.

If I use the existing project (phonegap), anyone can advice what to add or remove or change?

I am going to use storyboard as I am using XCode 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you from using the same bundle identifier. I have gone the other way (native to PhoneGap/Cordova) quite easily by just creating a new PhoneGap app and using the same bundle id and upping the version.